# How can I determine end-of-cursor in Rust using sqlite3 Select?

Tags: sqlite, rust

I'm just starting to evaluate Rust. Using Rust and the sqlite3 repo on Github, I'm attempting to determine EOF for a Cursor. I'm not sure how to do that "correctly", I think it may be via the "match" statement.

The 2nd line in the following 2 lines is how I'm currently determining EOF, but this is obviously not the "correct" way:

```
let oNextResult:sqlite::types::ResultCode = oDbCursor.step();
tDone = (fmt!("%?", oNextResult) == ~"SQLITE_DONE");
```

The following is the unfinished function containing the above 2 lines. Please excuse the lack of Rust naming-convention, but I will look at implementing that.

```
/********************
**** Update Data ****
*********************/
fn fUpdateData(oDb1:&sqlite::database::Database, iUpdateMax:int) -> bool  {
  println(fmt!("Updating %d Rows .......", iUpdateMax));

  let sSql:~str = fmt!("Select ikey, sname, iborn, dbal from test LIMIT %d",
                        iUpdateMax);    

  let oDbExec = oDb1.exec(sSql);
  if oDbExec.is_err() {
    println(fmt!("Select Failed! : %?, sql=%s", oDbExec, sSql));
    return false;
  }

  println("Select succeeded. Processing select list .....");
  let mut iUpdateCount: int = 0;
  let oDbCursor:sqlite::cursor::Cursor = oDb1.prepare(sSql, &None).unwrap();
  let mut tDone:bool = false;
  while !tDone {
    let oNextResult:sqlite::types::ResultCode = oDbCursor.step();
    tDone = (fmt!("%?", oNextResult) == ~"SQLITE_DONE");
    if !tDone {
      let sKey    = oDbCursor.get_text(0);  
      let sName   = oDbCursor.get_text(1);
      let sBorn   = oDbCursor.get_text(2);
      let sBal    = oDbCursor.get_text(3);
      println(fmt!("skey = %s, sname = %s, sBorn = %s, sBal = %s", sKey,
                    sName, sBorn, sBal));
      iUpdateCount += 1;
    }
  }
  println(fmt!("Update succeeded, items updated = %d", iUpdateCount));
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is a correct way at the moment but you can also the result codes from the types module:

```
use sqlite::types::ResultCode;
```

and then do something like this so there's no need for using fmt!

```
while cursor.step() == SQLITE_ROW {...}
```

or this:

```
while cursor.get_column_count() != 0 {...; cursor.step()}
```

Function get_column_count returns an int. If there's no data it will return 0. It calls `int sqlite3_data_count(sqlite3_stmt *pStmt);` under the hood and here's what sqlite docs say about it:

> The sqlite3_data_count(P) interface returns the number of columns in
>   the current row of the result set of prepared statement P. If prepared
>   statement P does not have results ready to return (via calls to the
>   sqlite3_column_*() of interfaces) then sqlite3_data_count(P) returns
>   0. The sqlite3_data_count(P) routine also returns 0 if P is a NULL pointer. The sqlite3_data_count(P) routine returns 0 if the previous
>   call to sqlite3_step(P) returned SQLITE_DONE. The
>   sqlite3_data_count(P) will return non-zero if previous call to
>   sqlite3_step(P) returned SQLITE_ROW, except in the case of the PRAGMA
>   incremental_vacuum where it always returns zero since each step of
>   that multi-step pragma returns 0 columns of data.

As it's mentioned on the readme file rustsqlite interface is not finalized, watch out for changes.

Comment: Thanks for that, that's great. I was hoping that there was an elegant solution, because I hate using "break;" - I know others disagree. I had to make a slight change to your solution as follows:   "while (oDbCursor.step() == sqlite::types::SQLITE_ROW) {" . If that is correct, you may want to edit your answer. BTW, I'm not using the repo in production yet, and I'm prepared for changes.

Comment: Changed SQLITE_OK to SQLITE_ROW.